# Verify the assembly of a second project when called from a multi-project Clickonce solution

Tags: c#, .net, security, dll, clickonce

I have a solution containing multiple projects. When deploying using clickonce - clickonce does not merge them into one assembly. Instead, there are multiple dll's. this might be a security risk when one dll calls a method from another dll. Especially if the process is elevated.

I'm not worried about the deployment itself because I can sign the manifest. I *am* worried about later - when a dll might be replaced by another one. Is there a way to have clickonce verify the second assembly by a signature **when it's accessed**?

Comment: Use the AppDomain.AssemblyLoad event to verify the assembly yourself http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyload(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .Manifest file in the deployment package tracks the .dll's that are deployed. If one of them changes then it will not run. Try copying over one of the .dll's with something else and see what happens.

If you are the one who needs to change the .dll, then you will build a new version of the solution and redeploy.